# Can I create custom templates for sources generated by Angular CLI

Tags: javascript, angular, code-generation

When I execute the following command in an Angular 9 project to generate e.g. a component

```
$ ng generate component
```

I would like to customize the sources generated - in particular the unit and e2e test files.

Is there a mechanism for me to provide templates, or modify existing ones?

they should also be accessible to all team members on my project.

I am aware of `yo generators`, but I'd prefer to stick with `ng`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are called Schematics and there is an official documentation for it.
You can find it here:
https://angular.io/guide/schematics

You can also find a lot of good guides around the Internet regarding this topic, i guess you were just missing the correct name to find the information :)

Comment: Oh wow - it looks pretty comprehensive - just what i was after. And yeah - the name was unknown to me